# Naive Set Theory by Halmos is confusing to a layman like me

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to be able to express set notations fluently in math fields used in machine learning, so I started reading [Naive Set Theory by Halmos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614271313).

But I have been facing a lot of problems like :

1. On pages 1-6 , I encountered `if and only if` and had to go to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if), to actually understand it .
2. Also , I had to search Math.SE to understand such sentences as :

> - It is equally harmless if the letter used has already been used with
>     *"for some"* or *"for all"*. Recall that *"for some $x \ (x \in A)$"* means
>     the same as *"for some $y \ (y \in A)$"* ; it follows that a judicious
>     change of notation will always avert alphabetic collisions.
> - *" nothing contains everything "*

---

Every page is a conundrum that requires huge amounts of mental gymnastics. I think I'm not ready to read the book, yet.

Can anyone recommend a better introduction to informal set theory than [Halmos](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614271313) ?

<sup>**My Background :** I majored in biology and attended calculus, statistics, real analysis, and linear algebra classes in a university. However, I dropped out of all math classes very early to focus on biology. Now, I want to learn math again. The high school didn't teach any theoretical foundation of math at all.</sup>

Comment: You can try with : Derek Goldrei, [Classic set theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=1dLn0knvZSsC&printsec=frontcover) (1996), but some "practice" with mathematical and logic symbolism is needed ...

Comment: You could start with the first two chapters of Discrete Mathematics by Rosen.

Comment: may I suggest, as a somewhat soft introduction, David Velleman's _How To Prove It_?

Comment: I liked Enderton better, but I haven't read neither of the books (Halmos, Enderton) to say. Just flipped through them for a few minutes.

Comment: Please note that "set notation" is quite different from set theory. While every mathematician is familiar with the former, a lot less are familiar with the latter, which is concerned with the theoretical foundations of the concept of set. I am not familiar with machine learning, but I doubt that it requires set theory. You might be better off studying some of the mathematics actually involved in machine learning, like statistics.

Comment: "If and only if" is completely standard mathematical terminology. I'm extremely surprised you never came across it before given that you've taken courses in, e.g., real analysis.

Comment: And if you see "iff" in a maths book, that's not a misspelling, it's short for "if and only if".

Comment: @DavidRicherby Note that I never touched math for 7 years after I dropped out of math classes early, so I forgot almost all of math completely.

Comment: @Minsky I'm guessing that the field of machine learning doesn't require all that much set theory. Much as I enjoy it myself, a whole textbook on it seems a bit much for someone in your position. You may get all the set theory and logic you need if you work through the tutorial that comes with my proof software (free, full-function download available at  my website http://www.dcproof.com ). I have tried to simplify set theory and logic to make them more accessible to math students transitioning to more proof-based courses, more like the kind you would see in math textbooks.

Comment: @Minsky , [How To Prove It](http://www.amazon.in/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521675995) is quite a nice little book - especially for beginners ; it helps you get nicely primed and ready for Proofs , First-Order Logic , Set Theory , Functions etc. After that , I would suggest you to pick up [Rosen](http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Kenneth-Rosen/dp/0072899050) -- wonderful book with lots of problems :)

Comment: I personally think *How to prove it* is less formal on its logic part. If one wants to learn the logic on the right way, see "Logic, Sets and Recursion" by Robert Causey. Just read the Chapter 1 of that book, you'll know why I consider it to be more rigorous, formal and "right".

Answer (score 40):

You are ready. You don't read math book like you read a novel. You can literally spend days on one page. You are not going to find a better book than Halmos's book; so you might as well grab a ton of scratch paper and go to town.

I do recommend that you get acquainted with the fundamentals of logic and boolean algebra first. You **must** become comfortable with *implies*, *if and only if*, *for all*, *there exists*, *and*, and *or*.

Since you have found your way into Stack Exchange, then you have access to quality help when your brain starts melting due to overload.

In terms of set theory, the phrase 'nothing contains everything' out of context, can be taken to mean either that the empty set contains all sets or that there is no such thing as the set of everything.

The first interpretation is ridiculous. The second is actually quite profound and has not always been believed.

Finally, there is something an old boss of mine once told me. "Nobody ever accomplished anything by reading the whole book." There is much in Halmos that you probably just don't need to know. Don't feel obliged to learn everything in the book.

Comment: Go back to your old boss, and tell him that if you read the whole book, you accomplish "reading the entire thing". Which you cannot possibly accomplish otherwise. :-D

Comment: But that's not how internet arguments work, @StevenGregory.

Comment: Does 'how to prove it' by velleman teach all I need to know?

Comment: @Minsky It will certainly get you up to speed on the basics of logic.

Comment: Where you say "can imply... or ...": you mean "can either be read to mean ... or to mean ...". I think you should formulate this more carefully, or it may add to the confusion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Maybe the old boss just wanted to say that nobody ever read the whole book ;-)

Comment: It has been said that everything on the internet that is said without a smiley face at the end will be taken seriously. I see now that even things with a smiley face at the end are taken seriously. (I was one of the first people to vote this answer, and I do agree with what you wrote there. Don't get me wrong about that. I never told anyone to read an entire book, if anything it's using something for reference, or reading several books.)

Comment: @StevenGregory No there is nothing wrong with editing answers, go ahead. Everybody does that around here. (Actually I cannot prove that. But I do it quite a lot myself.)

Answer (score 15):

> I want to be able to express set notations fluently in math fields
>   used in machine learning.

A book on set theory probably isn't the right place to be looking. Here's my advice:

1. Start off by trying to understand "propositional logic" (aka "boolean logic".) Start by Googling terms like "introduction to propositional logic." Perhaps get yourself a good introductory book on logic. Following sylvia's advice, consider getting your hands on [How To Prove It](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995) and/or similar books.
2. Once you understand propositional logic, make it your goal to understand "first-order logic." Try googling "introduction to first-order logic" and/or similar search terms.
3. Seriously, make sure you understand first-order logic. Being able to express one's ideas correctly using first-order logic is arguably one of the most important skills a mathematician must possess.
4. Realize that you don't have to use set-builder notation to express yourself unambiguously. In particular, observe that the following both express the same thing.

   - $A = \{x \in X \mid \mathrm{blah}\}$.
   - $A$ is the unique subset of $X$ such that (for all $x \in X$) the following are equivalent.

     - $x \in A$
     - $\mathrm{blah}$

Comment: Does 'how to prove it' by velleman teach all I need to know?

Comment: @Minsky , it is quite a nice little book - especially for beginners ; it helps you get nicely primed and ready for Proofs , First-Order Logic , Set Theory , Functions etc. After that , I would suggest you to pick up [Rosen](http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Applications-Kenneth-Rosen/dp/0072899050) -- wonderful book with lots of problems :) Happy 'Math'ing :)

Comment: Your phrasing in point 4 is very convoluted. Why not just say that "Let $X$ be the subset of $A$ containing exactly those elements that blah"?

Comment: @pranav How is discrete mathematics going to help me with my journey toward machine learning algorithms? Does it help me understand 'naive set theory' better?

Comment: Hi , @Minsky , discrete math is going to teach you logic , set theory , functions , a spattering of number theory , combinatorics , graphs , trees , automata theory , primarily . Amongst these , the most useful for ML would be Set Theory , functions , Combinatorics , Graph Theory and Trees . You will gain an insight into how to use principles like `Pigeonhole Principle` without any fuss . All this stuff , you will encounter while studying ML , so better to be comfortable beforehand . Hope this helps :) Any further questions , I am happy to answer :)

Comment: @Minsky, also the math that you actually , really want to learn is : Linear Algebra , Probability and Statistics  ;  set theory etc. you can pick up on the way , IMO . Have a look at [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) . Also , besides the math , learn programming in 1-2 languages preferably [Python](https://www.python.org) and some others amongst Java , C++ , Haskell etc. :D

Comment: @pranav I am already a good web programmer, and I want to become a very competent full-stack engineer and a machine learning researcher. I thought linear algebra, calculus, probability and statistics, and optimization theory were enough for machine learning. Can any of the fields I listed substitute discrete mathematics? I'd rather skip 800 pages of madness if possible.

Comment: @Minsky , if you are comfortable with writing proofs , playing around with the mathematical notation that ML Research entails , you are good to skip discrete math . Also , you do not need to read 800 pages . Do what you feel is comfortable - mostly a hit-and-trial approach (but it works !) :)

Comment: Hi @Minsky, I have tried to address your doubts [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235724/does-set-theory-help-understand-machine-learning-or-make-new-machine-learning-al/1249605#1249605) , hope that helps :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby, your suggestion is a good one if we don't need to mention the variable $x$. If we do, I do think my suggestion is not so bad. It has certain advantages. In particular, the phrasing I give makes it clear that anywhere you see $x \in A$, you can write "therefore blah", and anywhere you see "blah", you can write "therefore $x \in A$." The symmetry is clear. I also like making it very explicit that $A$ is a subset of $X$, which my phrasing does. If you can see how to shorten the whole thing without losing these qualities, I'd be interested to hear your ideas.

Comment: @goblin Fair enough, but note that my suggested phrasing make it clear that we're defining a subset of the original set (albeit that I accidentally put $A$ and $X$ the wrong way around).

Answer (score 8):

I think Halmos' *Naive Set Theory* is primarily concerned with set theory as a foundation on top of which mathematics is built, but the word "naive", if I understand correctly, just means he's viewing the concept of a set concretely as a collection of things rather than axiomatically as being whatever satisfies the axioms.  As to set theory applied to machine learning, it may be that what is needed differs from the content of Halmos' book.  I like the book by E. Kamke, which was reprinted by Dover Books, but I don't know how well suited to machine learning the topic is.  Is it useful in machine learning to know how to prove that $2^{\aleph_0}\ne\aleph_\omega$?  I wouldn't be surprised if it's not, but I don't know.

As for the difference between "for some $x$, ($x\in A)$" and "for some $y$, $(y\in A)$", it is the same as the difference between the first and last terms in this expression:
$$
\sum_{x=1}^5 x^2 = \underbrace{1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 +4^2 + 5^2}_{\text{No }x\text{ or }y\text{ appears here.}} = \sum_{y=1}^5 y^2. \tag 1
$$
$x$ and $y$ are "bound" variables here. There is a Wikipedia article about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables
The first and last expressions in $(1)$ are called "alphabetic variants" of each other.  If one is faced with an expression like
$$
\left(\sum_{i\in A}f(i)\right)\left(\sum_{i\in B} g(i)\right)
$$
it can be useful to write this alphabetic variant:
$$
\left(\sum_{i\in A}f(i)\right)\left(\sum_{j\in B} g(j)\right)
$$
because from that one can go on to see that this is equal to
$$
\sum_{i\in A}\left(\sum_{j\in B} \Big( f(i)g(j) \Big) \right).
$$
A similar thing happens when one wants to put formulas in first-order logic into what is called prenex normal form.

I would take "nothing contains everything" to mean that there is no set of which everything is a member.  In particular, in the conventional Zermelo–Fraenkel theory, no set is a member of itself.  Moreover, every set has more subsets than it has members, so its subsets cannot all be members of it, although in some instances some of them are.  See in particular this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem

Comment: Just to say that this is a very nice answer, but the explanation for "naive" in the title of the book is not quite right. It does give an introduction to axiomatic set theory (as it states in the preface); the "naive" comes from the theory so described being expressed in English rather than in the formal language of mathematical logic.

Answer (score 6):

While not exactly an introduction to set theory per se I considered [An Introduction to Proofs and the Mathematical Vernacular](https://www.math.vt.edu/people/day/ProofsBook/IPaMV.pdf) by Martin V. Day to be of great help in getting acquainted with a number of concepts and notations.
Although it's focus lies on reading, writing and checking proofs it provides all the necessary information to understand all those proofs. In my opinion it manages to keep the language simple and aids students to find their way by pointing out important caveats.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're reading the wrong book. Of course, if you want to continue reading Halmos for fun and/or the intellectual challenge, that's great, but what you're doing is the equivalent of trying to learn to drive by reading books about automotive engineering. A more mathematical analogy would be to think back to the courses you took on calculus and real analysis: the calculus course was about how to use differentiation and integration to solve problems, whereas the analysis course is about how differentiation and integration work "under the hood".

For machine learning, you will be a user of sets and you might do some calculation on sets but you won't be doing research into what sets *are* and what are the limits of what they can do. For your purposes, you don't really need to know what's "under the hood" and it will be entirely sufficient to say that a set is a collection of objects defined by some stated property. Yes, that way lies Russell's paradox but Russell's paradox only comes up if you use "weird" properties to define sets and you won't be going anywhere like that. In particular, essentially all the objects you'll come across that you might want to describe as "sets" will be subsets of something that definitely is a set, such as the integers. In those areas, set theory works in just the way you'd expect it to.

The first chapter of any undergrad textbook on general discrete mathematics will almost certainly contain all the set theory you need for machine learning.

Comment: Yes, that weird property of $x=x$ or $x\text{ has a single element}$...

Comment: @AsafKaragila But *users* of sets almost always have an implicit universal set in mind. There's nothing set-theoretically weird about "$x$ is an integer and $x=x$" or "$X$ is a set of vertices of my graph and $X$ has a single element."

Comment: So you're essentially taking more than you claim to have taken. You're using the fact that the integers are a set, or that your graph has a power set, and the availability of separation (or bounded comprehension). This is more than you claim in your answer, and the difference is exactly where understanding Russell's paradox. I'm not advocating for the OP to sit and plow through Jech and Kunen, or even through all of Halmos' book. I'm only pointing out that "those weird properties" might not be so weird, and that you need to understand a bit more than the minimal use, in order to make good use.

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming all of those things. Just like everybody who uses mathematics just assumes that the real numbers exist and have the obvious properties. As a computer scientist, almost every collection of objects I deal with is finite; almost all of the rest are countable and pretty much all the rest are finite unions of real intervals. So, yes, I can just assume that everything I want to call a set is a set and has all the expected properties.

Comment: One possible hiccup here is that machine learning involves a lot of probability so might involve some measure theory. I can imagine that that would require some actual set theory.